# Run stored procedure on linked server (linked server name as variable)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a script and its works well:

```
DECLARE @RunSPSQL VARCHAR(60);

SET @RunSPSQL = 'EXEC master.dbo.sp_test';

EXEC (@RunSPSQL) AT LNK_SERVER_NAME;
```

Now I would like to change linked server name to variable, something like this:

```
DECLARE @RunSPSQL VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE @LNK_Name NVARCHAR(60);

SET @RunSPSQL = 'EXEC master.dbo.sp_test';
SET @LNK_Name = 'LNK_SERVER_NAME';

EXEC (@RunSPSQL) AT @LNK_Name;
```

But it doesn't work:

> Incorrect syntax near '@LNK_Name'

I was looking for a solution, but no success for now.

If anyone, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a variable to replace the name of an object. Instead you need to use some dynamic SQL to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @RunSPSQL varchar(60);
DECLARE @LNK_Name nvarchar(60);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @RunSPSQL = 'EXEC master.dbo.sp_test';
SET @LNK_Name = N'LNK_SERVER_NAME';

SET @SQL = N'EXEC (@RunSPSQL) AT ' + QUOTENAME(@LNK_Name) + N';';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@RunSPSQL varchar(60)', @RunSPSQL = @RunSPSQL;
```

Just ensure you quote the linked server's name to avoid any injection.

Comment: You can use a variable to replace the name of an object in the case of `EXEC`. `DECLARE @RunSPSQL VARCHAR(60);SET @RunSPSQL = 'LNK_SERVER_NAME.master.dbo.sp_test';EXEC @RunSPSQL;` would work fine if all they want to do is run a stored proc

Comment: Note that `EXEC <four-part-name-sproc>` and `EXEC ('[EXEC] <sproc-name>') AT [linked server]` have [subtly different semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54334202/4137916). Fortunately you're not likely to notice unless you mess with the `remote access` option.