# SQL Linked server - Could not execute procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server 2012 [v11.0.6020] instances, `Test` and `Production`, with the same configuration.

On both servers I have a linked server created using this script

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver  
  @server='myLinkedServer', 
  @srvproduct='',       
  @provider='SQLNCLI10',  
  @datasrc='ERP01',   
  @location='',  
  @provstr='',  
  @catalog='Northwind'  

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin  
  @rmtsrvname = 'myLinkedServer',  
  @useself = 'false',  
  @rmtuser = 'user01',             
  @rmtpassword = 'user01pass' 

EXEC sp_serveroption 'myLinkedServer', 'rpc out', true;
```

On the test server I can run and get a result from below script

```
Declare @P01_In nvarchar(10),@P01_Out nvarchar(10) , 

EXEC myLinkedServer.Northwind.dbo.MyProc01 @P01_In,@P01_Out output

select @P01_Out
```

but if I ran same in the production server I get an error:

> Could not execute procedure 'MyProc01' on remote server 'myLinkedServer'

Note that remote access flag is '1' in both servers

Please suggest

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334202/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-against-linked-server

Comment: Thanks,  no it does not help, I guess [not sure though] its related to our Production server windows security setup, because same script run from the test server without any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved, by enabling "Allow inprocess" option for the linked Server Provider.
SQL Server Management Studio, Opne Linked Servers, Open Providers, select your linked server provider property then enable "Allow inprocess" option