# Execute stored procedure from Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have stored procedure stored in DB01 the name is `[cleanup].[spList_DB_Table_By_Column] @column_Name = 'customer_code'`, the stored procedure will find all column matched with the parameter supplied. So I want to run it in different server. How can I do that without writing the same SP in each different server?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334202/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-against-linked-server

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

```
EXEC [ServerName].[DBName].[schemaName].[spList_DB_Table_By_Column] @column_Name = 'customer_code'
```