Execute update statement with variables on remote server
I am using SQL Server 2019 and hit a snag in terms of performance where we use linked servers to push data into our target tables from the source server.
This used to work fine previously when the data volume was decent but as the system matured and data volume increased we hit performance issues. I'm trying to rewrite the stored procedures to execute on the remote target server instead. The stored procedures are either doing an update or an insert in the example below I have an update statement.
SQL:
DECLARE @RecordStartDate DATE = NULL;

IF @RecordStartDate IS NULL
    SET @RecordStartDate = GETDATE();

DECLARE @RecordEndDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @RecordStartDate);
DECLARE @updateQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @updateQuery = '
    UPDATE Tgt
    SET
        Tgt.CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = ''N'',
        Tgt.RECORD_END_DATE = @RecordEndDate,
        Tgt.RECORD_UPDATE_DT_TM = GETDATE()
    FROM [REMDB].[dbo].[TgtTable] Tgt
    JOIN [SRCDB].[dbo].[SrcTable] Src
        ON Tgt.ID = Src.ID
    WHERE Tgt.CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = ''Y''
        AND Src.CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = ''Y''
        AND (
            Tgt.NAME <> Src.NAME
            OR Tgt.LONG_NAME <> Src.LONG_NAME);
';

PRINT @updateQuery

EXECUTE ('EXEC sp_executesql N''' + @updateQuery + '''') AT [REMOTETARGETSERVER];

I run into incorrect syntax error and unable to pass variable value to the SQL query that I want to execute on the remote target server. The stored procedures are executed on the source server.

You're not passing @RecordEndDate into sp_executesql

@DaleK beat me to it. Tgt.RECORD_END_DATE = @RecordEndDate, this is not receiving the parameter. It is just a string

Right, I run into incorrect syntax error and unable to pass variable value to the SQL query everything shows up as a string.

This link talks about using parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334202/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-against-linked-server

I have a feeling you can exec linkedserver.sp_executesql directly without needing it to be dynamic... but I could be wrong about that.

Either that or pass the variables inside the EXEC, something like: EXEC('update t set somecolumn = ?', @yourparam1) AT [YourServer] This can be used to pass large jsons strings to insert data as well. But yeah, linked servers are always gonna be slow, you should look into other techniques in the long run.

As mentioned by @DaleK, you can call sp_executesql remotely, passing in parameters.
DECLARE @RecordStartDate DATE = NULL;

IF @RecordStartDate IS NULL
    SET @RecordStartDate = GETDATE();

DECLARE @RecordEndDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @RecordStartDate);
DECLARE @updateQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @updateQuery = '
    UPDATE Tgt
    SET
        CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = ''N'',
        RECORD_END_DATE = @RecordEndDate,
        RECORD_UPDATE_DT_TM = GETDATE()
    FROM REMDB.dbo.TgtTable Tgt
    JOIN SRCDB.dbo.SrcTable Src
        ON Tgt.ID = Src.ID
    WHERE Tgt.CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = ''Y''
        AND Src.CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = ''Y''
        AND (
            Tgt.NAME <> Src.NAME
            OR Tgt.LONG_NAME <> Src.LONG_NAME);
';

PRINT @updateQuery

EXEC REMOTETARGETSERVER.REMDB.sys.sp_executesql @updateQuery,
  N'@RecordEndDate date',
  @RecordEndDate = @RecordEndDate;

You can also just do the whole thing as a normal query, and in theory the local server should work out how to send that. Check the query plan to be sure it's not pulling back the whole tables and joining locally.
DECLARE @RecordStartDate DATE = NULL;

IF @RecordStartDate IS NULL
    SET @RecordStartDate = GETDATE();

DECLARE @RecordEndDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @RecordStartDate);

UPDATE Tgt
    SET
        CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = 'N',
        RECORD_END_DATE = @RecordEndDate,
        RECORD_UPDATE_DT_TM = GETDATE()
    FROM REMOTETARGETSERVER.REMDB.dbo.TgtTable Tgt
    JOIN REMOTETARGETSERVER.SRCDB.dbo.SrcTable Src
        ON Tgt.ID = Src.ID
    WHERE Tgt.CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND Src.CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND (
            Tgt.NAME <> Src.NAME
            OR Tgt.LONG_NAME <> Src.LONG_NAME);

